# What is this Space called?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics

We say $\mathcal H_2$ is a space contains all stochastic processes $F$ which satisfy:

(i) $(F_t, t \in [0,T])$ is adapted

(ii)$||F||_2 < \infty$

so what does this space H2 called here? does it have a name?

Comment: How is $\|F\|_2$ defined?  Is it $\|F\|_2^2 = \int_0^T E[F_t^2]\,dt$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a standard name for this space.

If the underlying probability space is $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, I've used the notation
$$L^2_a(\Omega \times [0,T], \mathbb{P} \times m)$$
where the $a$ stands for "adapted".  But I wouldn't expect anyone to recognize this notation without it being explicitly defined.

Comment: thanks, Im just wondering, because when my tutor told me he didnt say what this space called, and it reminds me L^p space p=2 its quite similar.

Comment: @DylanZhu: Indeed, it is a Hilbert space.